# Series of reciprocals of primes squared

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

I have to check the convergence of series $\sum_{p \in \mathbb{P}}^\infty \frac{1}{p^2}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all primes . I was thinking that I could compare this with the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$, which is bigger than our series since it contains more elements and by comparison test our series also converges. Is this a good enough argument?

Alternatively, this is a $p$-series (not to confuse $p$ with a prime) with $p=2$ and thus it converges. However I am still not sure if this argument is valid since we miss a lot of terms compared to $n=1 \to \infty$.

Comment: Comparison is good enough.

Comment: So my argument is enough even though I am not proving that it contains more elements?

Comment: Yes, the sum of $\frac 1{n^2}$ converges, so the prime-squares do too.

Comment: The sum with $n$ contains additional elements and all are positive, so is surely bigger than the sum with $p$ Totally valid argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using $p_n \geq n$ where $p_n$ denotes the n-th prime number proves your claim if you use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test.

Comment: Is there a proof required for $p_n \geq n$ ?

Comment: @mandella, this is quit trivial. Formal proof by induction: $p_1=2>1$ assuming that $p_n\geq n$, the $(n+1)$'th prime is greater than the $n$'th prime and so $p_{n+1}\geq p_n+1\geq n+1$.

Answer (score 3):

This is $P(2)$, where $P(s)$ is the [Prime Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function). The converge of $P(2)$ is indeed trivial, and its values is approximately
$$
P(2)=\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}=0.4522474200410654985065,
$$
see [this OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A085548) for references. The other series is $\zeta(2)=\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.