# What is the sum of the squares of reciprocals of primes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am a calculas student, and now I'm learning about convergent series. If you take the sum of the squares of reciprocals of primes up to infinity what would you get. I have seen a lot of diffrent opinions on this topic and they all give you an approximate solution like log(sqrt(5/2)). But I want to know the exact solution. My question is whether or not it has ever been found it's limit or we have just approximations?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking what is the limit of this sum: 1/2^2+1/3^2+1/5^2+1/7^2+1/11^2+1/13^2... and so on.

Comment: That's not true because the sum is less that the Basel problem which we know is equal to pi^2/6

Comment: See $P(2)$ for $P$ the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) and [A085548](https://oeis.org/A085548)

Comment: Sorry! Didn't see "squares of" in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Series of reciprocals of primes squared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676173/series-of-reciprocals-of-primes-squared)

Comment: Why do you think that there is a nice expression for this sum ?